# JS Array not selecting correct values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to select items from array using `slice()` method but it is not selecting right values.

```
var alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var show = alphabets.slice(1, 2);
console.log(` ${show} `);
```

It should output **B, D** but it is giving only: **B**

Array starting from zero **B** is 1 and from end **D** is 1

#### In other example.

```
var alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var show = alphabets.slice(1, 3);
console.log(` ${show} `);
```

Above code output: **B,C**

How this is even selecting elements?

Comment: The end parameter is exclusive.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: @YOU, JS Slice example here  https://jsfiddle.net/hj476myw/

Answer (score 3):

The slice() method selects the elements starting at the given start argument, and ends at, **but does not include, the given end argument**.

```
var alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
var show = alphabets.slice(1, 3);
console.log(` ${show} `);
```

Take your example, "D" is at position 3 so it will not include "D" in your output. It will only give "B" and "C" in your output.

Answer (score 2):

The `slice()` method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included). The original array will not be modified.

`arr.slice([begin[, end]])`

> **begin** Optional
>   Zero-based index at which to begin extraction.
>   **end** Optional
>   Zero-based index before which to end extraction. slice extracts up to but not including end.

```js
var animals = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'elephant'];

console.log(animals.slice(2));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck", "elephant"]

console.log(animals.slice(2, 4));
// expected output: Array ["camel", "duck"]

console.log(animals.slice(1, 5));
// expected output: Array ["bison", "camel", "duck", "elephant"]
```

If you have questions about JavaScript the Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) is a great place to go.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: Including a link to a source would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

This is the working principle of slice:
slice(start,end)
start is the start index and it starts from 0.
end is the end index, but does not include

In your case:

- A ---> index 0
- B ---> index 1
- C ---> index 2
- D ---> index 3
- E --->index 4

Thus, slice(1,2) will return only index "1" which is B

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation of Array.prototype.slice, as you have not used the second argument correctly.

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified

Refer to [MDN/JS/Array/slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

> The `slice()` method returns the selected elements in an array, as a
>   new array object.
>
> The `slice()` method selects the elements starting at the given start
>   argument, and ends at, but does not include, the given end argument.

see the below example with same array.

```js
    var alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
    
    console.log(alphabets .slice(2));
    // expected output: Array ["C", "D", "E"]
    
    console.log(alphabets .slice(2, 4));
    // expected output: Array ["C", "D"]
    
    console.log(alphabets .slice(1, 5));
    // expected output: Array ["B", "C", "D", "E"]
```

Answer (score 0):

slice() returns a copy of the array starting for the first index until a second index (NOT INCLUDED). If you want to start counting from the end on the second value you must use a negative index.

```
    var alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
    var show = alphabets.slice(1, 3);
    console.log(` ${show} `);
```

This will display BC

as well as:

```
    var alphabets = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
    var show = alphabets.slice(1, -2);
    console.log(` ${show} `);
```